# IIS Routing for Classic asp

Tags: iis, asp-classic

we have a classic asp site sitting on windows 2003. I'm embarking on a 2 phase upgrade that will see a rewrite to .Net. The focus at the moment is to get it off this server and onto 2012. The general structure of the site as it stands has a number of subfolders all with either images or documents. To help in the upgrade and future migration to .Net. I want to 'extract' these folders out of the wwwroot directory and place them in another folder following the same structure that they are currently in. Eventually there will be a proxy server involved to re-route. For now I don't have a proxy server, but for development I need to move these folders. Rather than go through each page and change `<img src=....` for example I'd like to tell IIS to map to a drive following the same structure for certain types if file (pdf,doc, jpg etc). Is this possible and if yes how do I do it? we are using IIS 8.5

Comment: You can move the whole structure (including the asp files) out of wwwroot and map the folder as a virtual directory.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for that. Can you just confirm how I should declare the alias. At the moment under my site I have folder1\images. So should the alias be folder1\images or just images on the basis that I'm making the virtual directory on the folder1 directory?